# Create a function such that...

Tags: functions, derivatives

I'm reading Kevin Houston's book "How to Think Like a Mathematician" and I came across this stumper:

> Find an example of a non-polynomial function $f:    \mathbb{R}    \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x)$ is negative for    $x <0$    and positive for $x \ge 0.$

Some functions that immediately came to mind were $f(x)=|x|$ and $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$, but in both of these cases $f'$ is undefined at $x=0$.

It seems to me that a graph of $f'$ will have to include a point at the origin extending into the first (NE) quadrant and contain an piece in the third (SW) quadrant that is asymptotic to the y-axis. We $\textit could$ make a piecewise definition and split $f$ into two parts, but this seems to go against the spirit of the question.

Ideas?

Comment: By "positive" you mean strictly positive and not merely $\geq 0$?

Comment: When you say "negative" and positive", do you mean it in the strict sense? If so, then you're not going to find an example that is differentiable everywhere by [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)).

Comment: Have you said what you intend?  If $f(x)=1/x^2$, then $f'(x)>0$ when $x<0$ and $f'(x) <0$ when $x>0$, which seems to be the reverse of what you're seeking.

Comment: @saulpatz Oops! Thank you. I meant to type $-\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: What if you multiply $|x|$ by $x^2$?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, $$f(x)=\cosh(x)-1$$ should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

What about $-\frac{1}{x^2+1}$?

The first derivative is $\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$ and that should fulfil (at least partly) the requirements.

The problem might be the $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}$, that is, the value reaches 0.. (as well as at $x=0$)

Comment: I don't see any conditions in the question about limits for $x\to\pm\infty$... but it does seem to require that $f'(0)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Start from $f'$. Pick any continuous function $f'(x)$ which is not a polynomial which satisfies the given condition (for example $f'(x)=e^x-1$ or some function which is not differentiable everywhere) and then pick $f(x)$ any antiderivative of it.

Comment: $e^x-1$ is not positive for $x\ge 0$ (only for $x>0$).

Comment: @Troposphere positive is unclear, it can mean strictly positive or greater or equal than zero.... If pozitive means strictly positive, then such a function does not exist by Darboux Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Another function that works is
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}.
$$